# change the background color of a multirow cell

Tags: tables, multirow, cellcolor

I hope you are doing well. I've made a multi-row cell by `\multirowcell`. How can I change the background color of this multi-row cell?

```
   \begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}\hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{text}&\cellcolor{yellow!10!gray}\multirowcell{5}{Numbers\\from\\ 1 to 5}&1 \\ \cline{1-2}\cline{4-4}
    x&x&\cellcolor{yellow!10!gray}&2 \\ \cline{1-2}\cline{4-4}
    x&x&\cellcolor{yellow!10!gray}&3 \\ \cline{1-2}\cline{4-4}
    x&x&\cellcolor{yellow!10!gray}&4 \\ \cline{1-2}\cline{4-4}
    x&x&\cellcolor{yellow!10!gray}&5 \\ \hline
    x&x &text&6\\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image]

I need the whole background color of cell which is highlighted by red line be changed.

Comment: Your question is not quite clear. Do you want to change the colour of the cell background or the text colour?

Comment: the background color of multirow cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution with `xcolor`:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{multirow, makecell}
    \usepackage[svgnames, table]{xcolor}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{|>{\columncolor{MistyRose! 50}}c|c|}\hline
    &1 \\
    &2 \\
    &3 \\
    &4 \\
    \multirowcell{-5}{Numbers\\from\\ 1 to 5}&5 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit*: here  is a code corresponding to  the edit of the post (same preamble as my initial answer):

```
    \begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|>{\columncolor{yellow!10!gray}}c|c|}\hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{text}& &1 \\ \cline{1-2}\cline{4-4}
    x&x& & \\ \cline{1-2}\cline{4-4}
    x&x& &3 \\ \cline{1-2}\cline{4-4}
    x&x& &4 \\ \cline{1-2}\cline{4-4}
    x&x& \multirowcell{-5}{Numbers\\from\\ 1 to 5} &5 \\ \hline
    x&x &\cellcolor{white}text&6\\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks. but i think your code change the background color of a column not just a multirow cell in a column. isn't it?

Comment: If you have more rows and  want the cells following the \multirow to have no background, you'll have to write at the beginning of each following cell `\cellcolor{white}`.

Comment: I did it for \multirowcell but it didn't work. i have to use \multirowcell not \multirow.

Comment: I had no problem when I tested. Could you post a short code reproducing the problem?

Comment: sure, I edit the code loaded in question and added a picture to make my question clear.

Comment: @MojtabaMansouri: please  see if my edit befits you.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow, makecell}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{table}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}\hline
            &1 \\
            \cellcolor{blue!20}&2 \\
            \cellcolor{blue!20}&3 \\
            \cellcolor{blue!20}&4 \\
            \cellcolor{blue!20}&5 \\ 
             \cellcolor{blue!20}\multirowcell{-5}{Numbers\\from\\ 1 to 5}&1 \\
            &6 \\\hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]